# User rebalance callback throws an error in kafka-solr-sink connector

Tags: solr, apache-kafka-connect

i am using kafka-solr-sink connector for the purpose of get the data from kafka topic to solr.
i got the following error. how to solve this.

```
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:422)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:439)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:358)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:490)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1275)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1241)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:448)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:228)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition TRAN-0 could be determined.
```

is there any environment related settings need to do?